# How to find accidentally deleted scheduled apex job?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I cant find it anywhere even recycle bin, can someone help me how to find deleted scheduled job in salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would be able to find the deleted scheduled job in recycle bin. You will have to recreate the scheduled job.

You can get the necessary information from **Setup > Monitor > Jobs > Apex Jobs.** From here you will get to know about the prior runs from which you can know which class was it executing and at what frequency, although it won't give you the exact frequency, but it will surely help you to recreate the scheduled job.

Another way of getting the information about the prior runs is by performing a SOQL on `AsyncApexJob`. You can get more information on `AsyncApexJob` at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) link.